# Swift. Data is loaded after then TableView

Tags: swift, networking, view, download, alamofire

I have 2 files. First - TransactionsViewController. Second - GetTransactions. When I open TransactionsViewController the table from that view loads faster than the date from GetTransactions. Therefore, it is displayed blank. How to fix it?
Here is the code of TransactionsViewController `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GetTransactions().getTransactions()
    clientsCount = GetTransactions.transactions.count
    setupNavBar()
    createTable()
    refreshSetup()
}
```

Here is the code of GetTransactions:

```
class GetTransactions {

    static var transactionsArr = [[String : Any]]()
    static var transactions = [TransactionInfo]()

    let URL_GET_TRANSACTIONS = "https://mashkov.dev/sites/default/BankApp/Transactions/Transactions.php"

    func getTransactions(){
        GetTransactions.transactionsArr.removeAll()
        AF.request(URL_GET_TRANSACTIONS).responseJSON{ (response) in
            if (response.value as? [[String : Any]]) != nil {
                GetTransactions.transactionsArr = response.value as! [[String : Any]]
            }
            self.convertData()
            print(GetTransactions.transactions)
        }
    }

    func convertData() {
        GetTransactions.transactions.removeAll()
        for transaction in GetTransactions.transactionsArr {
            let cl = TransactionInfo(id: transaction["id"] as! String,
                                     payee: transaction["payee_account_id"] as! String,
                                     sender: transaction["sender_account_id"] as! String,
                                     transDate: transaction["trans_date"] as! String,
                                     amount: transaction["amount"] as! String,
                                     isSuccessfully: Bool((transaction["isSuccessfully"] as! String)) ?? true)
            GetTransactions.transactions.append(cl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand asynchrone. `if (response.value as? [[String : Any]]) != nil {` will be called AFTER you think it will.

Comment: pass closure as an argument to `getTransactions` and execute it once you make API call and done with processing it. Reload table view in closure. You have what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a closure / block to be passed as an argument

```
class GetTransactions {

    static var transactionsArr = [[String : Any]]()
    static var transactions = [TransactionInfo]()

    let URL_GET_TRANSACTIONS = "https://mashkov.dev/sites/default/BankApp/Transactions/Transactions.php"

    func getTransactions(completion block: () -> ()){
        GetTransactions.transactionsArr.removeAll()
        AF.request(URL_GET_TRANSACTIONS).responseJSON{ (response) in
            if (response.value as? [[String : Any]]) != nil {
                GetTransactions.transactionsArr = response.value as! [[String : Any]]
            }
            self.convertData()
            print(GetTransactions.transactions)
            block()
        }
    }

    func convertData() {
        GetTransactions.transactions.removeAll()
        for transaction in GetTransactions.transactionsArr {
            let cl = TransactionInfo(id: transaction["id"] as! String,
                                     payee: transaction["payee_account_id"] as! String,
                                     sender: transaction["sender_account_id"] as! String,
                                     transDate: transaction["trans_date"] as! String,
                                     amount: transaction["amount"] as! String,
                                     isSuccessfully: Bool((transaction["isSuccessfully"] as! String)) ?? true)
            GetTransactions.transactions.append(cl)
        }
    }
}
```

And you call it using,

```
        GetTransactions().getTransactions {
            clientsCount = GetTransactions.transactions.count
            //reload your tableView here
        }
```